# Импорт SQL в БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, mysql

Ошибка

SQL-запрос:

```
# phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
# version 3.5.1
# http://www.phpmyadmin.net
#
# ����: localhost # ��
��� �������� : ��� 142013 �.,14 :06# ������ �������: 3.23.53 # ������ PHP: 4.3.6 # # �� : `
phpsite `
#

# --------------------------------------------------------

#
# ��������� ������� `articles`
#

CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id ` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  ` meta_d ` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `meta_k` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
   `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `desc ription ` text NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT =3;
```

Ответ MySQL:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3' at line 29
```

Непонятно, почему так.

Comment: Кодировка файла, может?…
А дамп с этой же БД делался?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE  `articles` (
 `id` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `meta_d` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `meta_k` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00',
 `description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `text` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `author` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =3
```

Comment: И ЧТО? ВСЕ РОВНО НЕ ПОРТИРУЕТ!

Comment: Алексей, я запустил этот код в phpMyAdmin и таблица прекрасно создалась без вывода описанных вами ошибок. Смотрите другие ошибки.